# CPU Registers and Multitasking

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, cpu-registers, multitasking

I'm currently learning Assembly and I'm confused how the CPU registers work with Multitasking. So in a Multitasking System. CPU can pause the execution of a certain program at any time and run another program. So how are the register values preserved during this step ? Are the registers pushed to stack or any other way ?

Comment: This is (involuntary) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch and done with help of hardware-generated (by timer) interrupt - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt. On interrupt CPU will pause program, save its registers to some place and jump to interrupt handler at some specific address. Some architectures may have hardware helpers for task switching, x86 had TSS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_state_segment and some x86 OS used it. With software context switch interrupt handler may save registers to PCB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block with OS-specific format.

Comment: WoW Thanks man... This is what I was looking for...

Comment: Dilhan, are you looking for x86/x86_64 or ARM? Linux or windows world?

Comment: x86 linux.........

Comment: But I hope its all the same concept ?

Comment: The basic idea is similar for many CPUs architectures. Either you have timer interrupt (100/300/1000 times per second) to check is current task was running for too long or is there task with higher priority (this part of OS is "scheduler"). If yes then task is switched (task switch). Or your task may do some long syscall ("blocking syscall") and can't continue until there will be return from this syscall (block read from disk, packet from network, etc) and the task will be switched too, but without additional interrupts. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/switch_to.h#L27

Comment: So what happens exactly when a blocking syscall happen ? will it switch the task or wait for the blocking call to end ?

Comment: Task state is changed to "blocked" inside kernel mode, the task will not be resumed. The syscall will call `switch_to` and switch to other task (process/thread). If there no useful threads, it will switch to special (secret) process with pid 0 (sometimes called swapper) which is doing `idle` in loop to cool CPU chip. Some intro to linux multitasking http://tldp.org/HOWTO/KernelAnalysis-HOWTO-6.html with example of some register store/load in "6.6 Task Switching"

Comment: Great... Thanks allot man

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> how the CPU registers work with Multitasking.

CPU basically may not work with multitasking, task switch may be (and is) implemented in software. Some CPU (intel x86) may have hardware state (TSS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_state_segment) and TR (task register) to atomically change state from one task to another. (TSS may still be used to switch [protection rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) ring0/ring3; but not to switch tasks.)

> So in a Multitasking System, CPU can pause the execution of a certain program at any time and run another program.

Almost.

In most CPU, capable of running OS and user-space tasks, there are [*interrupts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) which are used in case of some external event (signal from hardware, interrupt request, IRQ) to pause execution of current code (task) and to jump to one of several special kernel functions, called [interrupt handlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) (ISR, interrupt service routine).

> So how are the register values preserved during this step ?

Most registers just stays untouched on interrupt entry. Some are preserved by CPU in interrupt entry process.

Interrupt support mechanism is implemented inside CPU, it does save *some* cpu registers of current task to some space (yes, it [can save](http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt#From_the_CPU.27s_perspective) [to stack](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Advanced_Interrupts#The_Interrupt_Vector_Table), x86 cpu pushes *FLAGS, CS, IP). CPU jumps to these routines, registered in [Interrupt Vector Table](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Advanced_Interrupts#The_Interrupt_Vector_Table) / [Interrupt Descriptor Table](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Advanced_Interrupts#The_Interrupt_Descriptor_Table) (IDT) arrays (stored at special memory location in case of IVT or pointed by special CPU register IDT for IDT); for IRQ 1 it will select record number 1 (routine 1); for IRQ 20 it will select routine 20.

> Are the registers pushed to stack or any other way ?

Both. Some are pushed by CPU in interrupt, and some are pushed by commands of interrupt handler. (And there is also code to change EIP in kernel mode...)

ISR routine knows what was saved by CPU, and if it want to use some more registers (it basically wants), it will push to stack (or save to other place) other user registers, then do its interrupt work, then restore manually saved registers back, and then will exit from interrupt using special command ([`iret` in x86 word](http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt#From_the_OS.27s_perspective), it will reload "CS:IP and FLAGS" back from stack). If original IP was untouched in the stack, CPU will continue execution of original user code (original task), and it will have all registers unchanged. If author or interrupt handler wants, he may change IP address in the stack before doing `iret`, so it will return in other place (it may return to kernel mode or to some task or reboot PC and so on).

Changing current running task (context switch, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), [osdev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching)) is one of problems which may be done using interrupts. There are basically two kinds of context switching: *involuntary* (when the task just runs and do not want to leave CPU) and *voluntary* (when task asks OS to do the context switch, either because current task may no run further or if current task is polite and gives other tasks chance to run - [sched_yield](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) in linux world).

Involuntary context switch is usually done with help of periodic timer interrupt. Several years ago this timer used to generate some specific IRQ (timer/RTC IRQ) every 10, 1 or 3 milliseconds; and timer interrupt handler calls OS [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) to decide is current task runs for too much time (exceeds its [time slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice), the quantum of [time-sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-sharing)) or is there some task with higher priority ready to run.

Voluntary context switch is usually done with help of system call (when OS used privilege separation, runs user-space code in ring3 and kernel-space code in ring0 - concept of [protection rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring)), which is special CPU instruction to switch between privilege levels (it may be / was implemented with software-generated interrupts; [`int 80h`](http://www.int80h.org/) in older linux/BSD). User-space code asks kernel to do some work, for example `read` from file or socket or `write` to file. It also may ask kernel to run scheduler to switch to other task if there is any - with [sched_yield](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) syscall. If syscall code decides that request need some time and the task can't run further before the request is done (system call [blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309136/what-is-meant-by-blocking-system-call) - blocks current task from running; switches it state from [`TASK_RUNNING`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/KernelAnalysis-HOWTO-6.html)), it will also call OS scheduler.

OS scheduler may keep current task as running (if it is in runnable state) or may decide to switch to other task (actually to kernel-mode of other task; there also will be return-from-syscall to restore task's CS:IP+FLAGS) and do it using `switch_to` asm macro: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/switch_to.h?v=4.6#L27:

```
 33         /*                                                              \
 34          * Context-switching clobbers all registers, so we clobber      \
 35          * them explicitly, via unused output variables.                \
 36          * (EAX and EBP is not listed because EBP is saved/restored     \
 37          * explicitly for wchan access and EAX is the return value of   \
 38          * __switch_to())                                               \
 39          */                                                             \
 40         unsigned long ebx, ecx, edx, esi, edi;                          \
 41                                                                         \
 42         asm volatile("pushfl\n\t"               /* save    flags */     \
 43                      "pushl %%ebp\n\t"          /* save    EBP   */     \
 44                      "movl %%esp,%[prev_sp]\n\t"        /* save    ESP   */ \
 45                      "movl %[next_sp],%%esp\n\t"        /* restore ESP   */ \
 46                      "movl $1f,%[prev_ip]\n\t"  /* save    EIP   */     \
 47                      "pushl %[next_ip]\n\t"     /* restore EIP   */     \
 48                      __switch_canary                                    \
 49                      "jmp __switch_to\n"        /* regparm call  */     \
 50                      "1:\t"                                             \
 51                      "popl %%ebp\n\t"           /* restore EBP   */     \
 52                      "popfl\n"                  /* restore flags */     \
 53                                                                         \
```

If there was the only non-sleeping user task and it goes to sleep, there are no visible tasks ready to be run. But in fact there is invisible task with pid 0, sometimes called swapper or [idle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_(CPU)), which has lowest priority and always ready to run. It will run some special CPU instruction in loop to cool down the CPU - [HLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT_(x86_instruction)); it may also do some checks for events / calls to scheduler to find runnable tasks.

Some strange realtime OS (with name starting from "V" and ending in version 5) without user-space/kernel-space separation and isolation (all code runs in ring 0) may implement voluntary context switch without syscall or software interrupts; but by usual call to scheduler.

Useful links:

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Advanced_Interrupts
- http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt
- http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=364068 - How Multitasking Works at the Hardware Level, 2005, chapter of very good book "Unabridged Pentium 4, The: IA32 Processor Genealogy".
- [Task management on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992825/task-management-on-x86) mentions "Protected Mode Software Architecture" book and "Understanding the Linux Kernel, 3rd Ed.", Bovet, chapter 3 Processes, 3.3.2. Task State Segment.
- http://wiki.osdev.org/Task_State_Segment of hardware task switching

Answer (score -1):

> CPU can pause the execution of a certain program at any time and run another program. So how are the register values preserved during this step ? Are the registers pushed to stack or any other way ?

Most processors define a Process Context Block (PCB) structure that is used to save the process registers when its execution is suspended. Such processors also have a Save Process Content and Load Process Context  instruction that save or load the register set in one step.

Registers are not pushed on the stack.

A process switch looks something like:

```
SAVEPROCESSCONTEXT address_of_running_process_pcb
LOADPROCESSCONTEXT address_of_new_process_pdb
```

In most systems, interrupts are serviced by whatever process is running at the time so there is no suspension of the process.

Comment: user, what volume and page of Intel Architectures Software Developer Manual  (definition of x86/x86_64 cpu architectue) should I check to find definition of PCB Block? Why Wiki says about PCB as part of OS, not of CPU? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block "... is a data structure *in the operating system kernel* containing the information needed to manage a particular process. The PCB is "the manifestation of a process **in an operating system**"". What is the "Save Process Content" instruction in x86, arm, mips?

Comment: Intel uses a bizarre system. You need to look at the Task State Segment and the XSAVE (and related instructions-chapter 13). The PCB is maintained by the OS. The CPU defines structure structure.

Comment: CPU still don't define PCB structure, only TSS. And TSS is not used by most OS.

Comment: CPU architectures DO define PCB structures. Otherwise, they would not know where to save the registers. As I said, the intel system is  a true oddity. Most processors intended for multi-processing have some provisions for a PCB.

Comment: Example: http://www.itec.suny.edu/scsys/vms/OVMSDOC072/72final/4515/4515pro_030.html#4515ch9_220

Comment: VAX is alive? It may never die? Ok, VAX had hardware context save/restore. Any other used architecture?

Comment: There is similar in the 68000.

Comment: user33, what was names of task switch instructions in 68k?